# Solve inequality involving product of x terms

Tags: probability, inequality, products, birthday

What is the minimum value of $x$ such that

$$1-\prod_{k=0}^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{k}{2^{160}}\right)>0.01$$

is true?

Is there any easy way to solve this without using computational software?

Comment: We can solve this to get some idea: $1 - (1-\frac{1}{2^{160}})^x \gt 0.01$. Approximating, we get $1 - (1 - \frac{x}{2^{160}}) \gt 0.01 \implies x \gt 2^{160} * 0.01$

Comment: @sku, Claude Leibovici's answer suggests x is around $1.71 \times 10^{23}$, while your answer suggests x is at least $2^{160}/100 \sim 1.46 \times 10^{46}$. That's a pretty large difference in the order of magnitude. Are you sure about your approximation?

Comment: sorry, it is a very large upper bound. Claude is right.

Comment: In an edit, I added the exact values of $x$ for the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the problem more general, consider the equation
$$1-\prod_{k=0}^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{k}{a}\right)=\epsilon \tag 1$$ where $a$ is a huge number $(2^{160} \sim 1.46 \times 10^{48})$ and $\epsilon \ll 1$.

Rewriting $(1)$
$$\prod_{k=0}^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{k}{a}\right)=1-\epsilon \tag 2$$  Take logarithms of both sides
$$\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}\log\left(1-\frac{k}{a}\right)=\log(1-\epsilon) \tag 3$$ Using Taylor
$$\log\left(1-\frac{k}{a}\right)=-\frac{k}{a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$ Summing over $k$
$$-\frac{(x-1) x}{2 a} \sim - \epsilon$$ Assuming that $x$ is large
$$x^2 \sim 2a \epsilon \implies \color{red}{x\sim \sqrt{2a \epsilon}}$$ So, for your case $x\sim 1.71 \times 10^{23}\sim 2^{77}$.

Computing rigorously for $a=2^{n}$, $\epsilon=0.01$ this would give  for the product
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x & \prod_{k=0}^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{k}{2^n}\right) \\
 10 & 5 & 0.990268 \\
 15 & 26 & 0.990128 \\
 20 & 145 & 0.990093 \\
 25 & 819 & 0.990067 \\
 30 & 4634 & 0.990052 \\
 35 & 26214 & 0.990051 \\
 40 & 148291 & 0.990050
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

For the inequality, the exact  values of $x$ are : $5,26,145,821,4646,26280,148664$

Answer (score 0):

We can certainly do better than what I have in my comment above. Let $w = 2^{160}$
For example,

$1-\prod_{k=0}^{x-1}\left(1-\frac{k}{2^{160}}\right) $

$ = 1 - (1 - \frac{1}{w})(1 - \frac{2}{w})\dots (1 - \frac{x-1}{w})$

Multiplying the outer most two and going inwards, we get:
$ = 1 - (1 - \frac{x}{w})^{x/2} \approx \frac{x^2}{2w} > 0.01 \implies x > \sqrt{0.02} * 2^{80} \approx 2^{77} $

where I used $(1 - \frac{1}{w})(1 - \frac{x-1}{w}) \approx 1 - \frac{x}{w}$